# Consume AMF methods without Flash using .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, apache-flex, air

I would like to know if it is possible to consume a AMF Service using .NET. I would like to consume a AMF service written in PHP using my ASP.NET Application, that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [FluorineFx](http://fluorinefx.com/).  It has .Net AMF libraries.

Comment: @James, thanks for you answer,but looking up fluorinefx docs I foundnt' anything that could help me.

Comment: You might want to ask on their email list.